# SQL : How do I construct a select query with conditional where clauses?

Tags: sql

I would like to perform an SQL select query with conditional 'and' clauses but am having difficulty.

I would like to do something like this:

```
select * from customer
    where active = true
    and 
    case 
    when state = 'AK'
        then zipcode like '%701'
    when state = 'NV'
        then zipcode like '%523'
    else
        then phone not null;
```

How do I go about structuring my query to do this?

Thanks in advance for any guidance provided.

Comment: maybe you should try to read the documentation. This is for **[SQL SERVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `or` instead of `case`.

```
select * from customer
where active = true
and ( (state = 'AK' and zipcode like '%701') or (state = 'NV' and zipcode like '%523') )
and phone is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean?

```
select * from customer
where active = true
and ((state = 'AK' and zipcode like '%701')
    or (state = 'NV' and zipcode like '%523')
    or (phone not null))
```

Comment: I think that `or` works as `and/or` . So he will be needing an exclussive `or` I guess